# Visual Studio 2015 Outlook AddIn + Office 365 Click to run

Tags: visual-studio-2015, office365, outlook-addin

I've made a Visual Studio Outlook Add-in using the project template:

Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in

Then I have a setup project from InstallShield Limited Edition 2015 to register this Add-in.
The add-in works fine on computers with:

- Microsoft Office 2013 Professional
- Microsoft Office 2016 Professional

But, the add-in does not work on computers with:
* Office 365 ProPlus

The add-in does not show in the COM add-in, and if I try to add it manually, it says that is not compatible.

I've been reading around some sites\blogs and found some information about Office 365 Click to run, a way to install the Office apps with one click, and they say that this method have some benefits but some add-ins might not work or have problems:

> Click-to-Run is also designed to allow locally-installed add-ins and dependent applications to work with it. However, there is the possibility that some add-ins or other integration points with Office might behave differently or might not work when you are using Click-to-Run.
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219427.aspx

Is there anything I can do to make my add-in work with Office 365 ProPlus click to run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having similar issue, the old add-in doesn't get registered in Office 365(proplus), need to go inside the installation folder, manually run the vsto file.

Answer (score 0):

One of our content developers suggested this information on MSDN, about configuring a computer to develop Office solutions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx. There is a section on troubleshooting project templates.

Hope that helps!

Freya, The Office Newsroom